# highstock, how to prevent chart rescaling

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am experimenting with highcharts and there is one thing that **many charts have as a functionality** and that is to rescale the current view to show only the datapoints that currently are in view to fit the chart.

For instance, given these datapoints on a large time period, :

```
[1, 50, 100, 1, 50, 100, 200 ]
```

The chart will show up initially with a scale of say 1 - 200.

When you then move the chart left to view older data, 200 gets out of the view, and the graph gets rescaled into 1 - 100, then 1 - 50, then 1 - 1, then it grows again to 1 - 100.

The **problem** **with this** should be **obvious**. 
If you are trying to get any sense of the data by scrolling back in history, you can't really.

Although I do agree that sometimes it is desirable to rescale, it isn't always the case.

Sometimes you just want to view the graph as is, using a large range around large discrepancies in the data, without rescaling to try to fit all datapoints.

I have tried to set **reflow: false** but this did not work.

Any ideas on wether this is possible or not?

**Edit:**

Here is a fiddle that attemps to show some of these problems in example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3Ld2zmum/1/

If you just scroll on the default zoom, then you will suddenly see there is a datapoint that in my case should be ignored. I would like to see the data around it. I do not want it to affect the zoom level.

Right now, I am prevented from effeciently analyzing data around this point because the graph keeps scaling up and down.

The problem with rescaling is that a high/low datapoint will automatically zoom all other data out so it becomes really small when there are hugh sudden variances in the dataset.

I can choose a small timeperiod, but then it becomes really difficult to analyze huge amounts of data with such a small range.

**After having thought about this**, i understand that the only way to solve this issue would be to introduce some kind of scroll on the y axis, so that when you move left, you will actually **see only white space**.

You would have to manually scroll down to see the data. That way, the scaling won't interfer with the actual direction of the data and you won't get confused by data that can change the flow of the data.

In such circumstances again, it would sometimes be preferable to just allow scroll left, without rescaling, allowing the data to get out of view on the y-axis, and allowing you to study data around the big discreprancy without adjusting the rangeSelector to a really small one to avoid such datapoints on short intervals.

Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the auto-scaling of the yAxis you can set the [`yAxis.min`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.min) and [`yAxis.max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.max) values like so:

```
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 13000,
        title: {
            text: 'AAA'
        }
    },
```

Yes, you will need to set some sort of max value either by knowing ahead of time what the max should be or by calculating the data's max value and adding some kind of padding.

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that before, but now it does work. However, this does introduce other problems. When you navigate left you are unable to manually alter the y position. Ideally in this situation I need to either scroll the y axis, that is dynamically adjust ymin and ymax on demand. Is it possible to dynamically change these values after first draw?

Comment: You can set your zoom level: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType. Use `y` or `xy`.

Comment: @momo, the chart is already "dynamically adjusting the ymin and ymax on demand" when you do not set a hard min/max.

Comment: yes, it does so. when zoomType is set to xy it is possible to adjust inbetween y and min which allows for what one could call "scrolling" but it is very bad for this purpose. Eventually the resolution goes down to almost 1 point if min:0 and max:12000. Try to zoom into the bottom of one of the spikes and try go to the top. Would it be possible to listen to some events and set min and max myself?

Comment: You could remove min/max and let highcharts do it for you with enabling xy zoomtype.

Comment: Yes, enabling y zoom with min max, then zoom seems to temporarily get into the mode I am asking for. The reset zoom gets you back. I guess that is  good, but ideally, i'd still see it valuable to be able to disable the autoscale completely while being able to scroll on the y axis.

Comment: Then set min/max - that disables the autoscale.

Comment: Couldn't the scroll wheel be used to scroll on the y axis? y max could then be decreases by a variable amount. Or introduce a scroll tool for the y axis that does this when the option is set.

Comment: If I set min max then that's works, but I still can't scroll, so it not really a good option. Can i set min, max and then dynamically turn them off/on at will?

Comment: @momo I am not really sure what you are looking for here. You say you want to turn off autoscale but you want the yAxis to autoscale? Scrolling on a yAxis (value axis) is not really a good idea in any case as it obscures the data context.

Comment: I want to turn off scale and be able to scroll left and right. Eventually the data might get out of screen such as in the case when the data keeps going lower and lower as we go back in time. When we scroll left to much eventually there might be a need to manually scroll down on the y axis, this would alter the ymin and ymax by subtracting 1 from ymax and subtracting 1 from ymin. Scrolling left now still shouldn't autoscale. You mentioned that I could set ymin ymax but the problem is that it is set in stone completely. Shouldn't there be a way to hook into this and modifiy ymin and max after?