# How do I prevent Highstock y-axis scaling on non-visible series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a Highstock chart with a number of series on it (some of which only intended to show on the tooltip without being visible).  I don't know the approximate scale for my y-axis ahead of time (as the data is loaded on the fly from a backend), but it seems like I'm hitting some of the `setExtremes` limitations in Highcharts.

My goal is to have a chart that looks something like this (notice the use of `max` to define the upper range of the y axis):

http://jsfiddle.net/d1mchqe0/1/

while still having a tooltip that works as shown in this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/d1mchqe0/2/

Any suggestions on how to handle this?  Seems like my best bet may be to do manual max calculations (as suggested here: [highstock, how to prevent chart rescaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29925656/highstock-how-to-prevent-chart-rescaling)) but I'd like to avoid that if possible ;-)

Comment: If I have understood you right, you want to reach a situation where the chart has a y axis which prevents certain series from being shown while still displaying their values in the tooltip. Is that correct? One way to do this is to have a custom tooltip and not show the other time series at all.

Comment: Maybe you can use yAxis.setExtremes() after you will load your series basing on this series max value. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes

Comment: @nilsole Yes, I'm currently doing a custom tooltip, but it gets cumbersome as I add more series.  Currently I've got about 7 and that will only grow.  So would like to have things as low maintenance as possible ...